# IE7 pushes down content past float

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-float

I have a layout with a left vertical nav and a main content area.  The main content area has some info floated right, and its contents may be wider than the browser window.  This works how I want with Firefox/Chrome/IE8, but with IE7, the wide content gets pushed down below the nav menu.

Problem demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/UX2ac/

With the test page

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.nav {
   float: left;
   width: 5em;
   background: lightgreen;
}
.content {
   background: lightyellow;
   margin-left: 5em;
}
.extraInfo {
   background: lightblue;
   float: right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="nav">
      left<br/>
      nav<br/>
      menu<br/>
      items
   </div>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="extraInfo">
         Right info!
      </div>
      <p>Page Desc</p>
      <!-- <h3>Content</h3> -->
      <div style="white-space: nowrap">
         stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff stuff 
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This renders correctly in IE8 as:
[image]

But in IE7, it shows as:
[image: IE7 broken]

I know that I could get "side by side" divs to work with `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` in a parent, but then the content div's width would expand to include the full size of its content, pushing the right extraInfo div off the screen.  Same thing if I replaced nav  & content with a 2-cell table.

How I can get IE7 to render this the same as everything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `"display: inline-block;"` to your content element's style and it will force IE7 to render the same as other browsers.

Here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UX2ac/2/).

Comment: Yes, but the point is there will be content wider than the window.  We can replace the "stuff" words with http://wwww.test.com/thisIsAreallylonglinkthatwillcauseproblems/waytoowide/page.aspx?stateInfo=agaeruhaeaergakerhaerghaerg and it'll still break.

Comment: yea it is strange because IE7 supports "nowrap" so, I am trying a few different things with the markup now

Comment: I don't want to constrain everything to the width of the div. I want it sticking out with a scrollbar, like it does in the IE8 screenshot.  The only thing I don't want it to do is push down past the menu.

Comment: I had a tough time understanding this one but I think that I found a solution. You tried `display: inline-block` on a parent element without any luck but it seems to work on the content element, itself.

Comment: That does it!  Can't say I understand why, but I'm willing to throw my arms up at the IE 7 black magic and continue on.  Thanks!